# Three Column Layout with Collapsing Sidebars and Statically Sized Middle

Tags: css, html

I can't figure out how to make this layout properly:

```
_________________________________________
| #Header div                            |
| position:fixed; width:100%;            |
|________________________________________|
|#bgleft      | #main        |#bgright   |
|min-width:0; |width:1000px; |min-width:0|
|max-width:460|              |max-w:460  |
|scroll:fixed |              |           |
|_____________|______________|___________|
|footer div, position:fixed; bottom:0;   |
|________________________________________|
```

Basically I want #bgleft and #bgright to not be necessary so they don't count towards the document width, so if the viewport is 1000px or smaller it only shows the #main div. But if the window is larger, say 1200px, it would show the main div 1000px plus 100px each of the bgleft and bgright divs. Hope that makes sense and thanks for your input!

edit: I forgot to mention I want the #bgleft and #bgright images to behave like scroll:fixed so that those images always stay "connected" to the header and footer divs. I'm essentially trying to create a little "window" around the #main div, but I want the bgleft and bgright to not be necessary unless the window is large enough to show them.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7Y7TJ/13/ (this is the closet I've been able to get but the problem is that the #bgleft div isn't fixed position as the #main content scrolls down)

Comment: Well, first I'd start with a text file, give it a name and a `.css` file ending. Then... Oh you mean literally? The easy way is to use the [holy grail](http://www.glish.com/css/7.asp). `;)`

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I see that link is not entirely working. Here's a lineup of many different layouts: http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Three_Column_Layouts

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but in that example the center div has a dynamic width, the left and right divs aren't fixed position and don't collapse when the window shrinks.

Comment: I've looked at a bunch of 3 column layouts but the behavior that is hard for me to get is to have the left and right be "collapsable" i.e. not count towards document width, and to also have images within them that "stick" next to the #main div but again don't count towards document width.

Comment: What you're wanting to do with the sidebars is one, sorta unorthodox since what happens to their content when they're 23px wide?, and two, I think you'll probably need Javascript to actually manage this if you want the width of the sidebars to be relative to the width of the main column minus the width of the screen (header/footer widths). CSS will have a hard time "calculating" that.

Comment: Interesting question, though, +1. Do you have a http://jsfiddle.net demonstrating what you have so far?

Comment: Jared, here is what I have so far, it's somewhat close but not exactly what I'm going for: http://jsfiddle.net/7Y7TJ/

Comment: I put it in your question so others will see it.

Comment: Resize your window to the left and right to see how the left image can "disappear" if the window is too small, and how the horizontal scrollbar only appears if the window width is smaller than the #main div.

Comment: I made a slight edit to remove the unnecessary markup (fiddle adds everything but what's in the `body` tag, including the `body` tag). Are you using HTML5 doctype?

Comment: I'm not using any doctype currently, I don't know enough to know how that impacts things ;x

Comment: I did find a way doing the "if they flow under that's fine" mold. I'm check now to see how bastardized it appears in IE, but it works in FF13 and Chrome Latest.

Comment: I found a solution which seems to work in all browsers. Check it out and let me know what you think.

Comment: Be aware the template I posted still needs some work. I've removed it for now until I can resolve the problems I was seeing (mainly, it's not flowing down the page with the content).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best solution I've found to what I'm trying to do:

Put a #wrapper div around #main, and use the following css for #wrapper:

```
background-image: url(bgtest.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center 0;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I THINK you're after, I don't see why you wouldn't be able to do this in CSS without the need to resort to any JS.

You can use different "@media screen" tags in your stylesheet to force the page to use different styles depending on browser size.

For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) { CSS GOES HERE }
```

The above would display whatever style you define when the viewport size is up to 1199px wide.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) { CSS GOES HERE }
```

The above would display an alternate style on browser windows over 1200px wide.

You can also combine max-width and min-width to display styles between ranges, such as:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1200px) { CSS GOES HERE }
```

That would display a particular style if the viewport is between 1000px and 1200px.

I'm pretty sure that everything you want to do can be done within that sort of set up. There's a risk of getting too bogged down with superfluous JS and JQ from what I can tell, but it seems somewhat superfluous.

Comment: I suppose I'd like to see a working demonstration. I see what you're suggesting, but... I'm still skeptical.

Comment: The only issue I can see personally is IE7,8 not working with media queries, but you can add in a JS script to get them playing ball. After that, I don't see any problems with the above solution (providing what I think Drew wants to do is actually what he wants to do).

Comment: I think the problem with this (and correct me if I'm wrong as I haven't actually tried it yet.. will give it a shot in a sec), is that the side images won't dynamically draw and only show part of the image based on the screen width. I just posted a jsfiddle that will hopefully further explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Drew - I was thinking you wanted it dynamically calculated. That's probably the biggest impediment to a solution that's CSS-only.

Comment: For the #bg divs, I want their top position fixed (right under the header div), and ya I guess I do want the left/right of the #bg divs to be dynamically caluclated, but relative to the #main div, if that makes sense?

Comment: Am I right in thinking you want the images dynamically resized based on the layout? So if a browser is under 1000px, images are downscaled to match the size of the layout etc etc?

Comment: No I don't need the images resized or scaled at all. I'm ok with them only partially showing. So if the window is say, 1100px wide, it would show the 1000px main div and only the right 50px of the bgleft div and the left 50px of the bgright div, so those images would be cut off rather than scaled/resized.

Comment: @Drew - So in other words, if the left/right columns were "underneath" the center column and "hidden", that would be ok?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm going for.

Comment: I just don't think it's going to be simple to do this dynamically with CSS only and not have the approach be "abstract". If someone can prove me wrong, I'd be happy to entertain having my shoe as dinner.

Comment: As you can see in my jsfiddle I "ALMOST" have it working as intended. I think I could use jquery to change the bg divs to position:fixed as the window scrolls, and adjust their left/right based on document width and #main position... just don't know if I want to go that route.. I think this is possible with css only, I just can't get it!

Comment: Well, I got something sorta close: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/QNkwp/ The problem is, the width of the left/right sidebars are adding the overall page width.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I've actually found a very nice solution where I can just put a background image in #wrapper div and achieve the effect I want. It just involves creating a background image that is blank for the width of the #main div, and extends past it.

 background-image: url(bgtest.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center 0;

Comment: Ok. Do you have a fiddle? Just so we can see what you were thinking?

Comment: I can't figure out how to use images in jsfiddle :o

Comment: @Drew - You just link to them from your site or whereever it's located.

Comment: Here is how I'll probably end up doing it: http://jsfiddle.net/7Y7TJ/17/ . The only "problem" I have with this technique is, like I said, I have to make a large background image with 1000px (or 300px in the jsfiddle example) of blank space. But other than that it is a very nice technique!

Comment: @Drew - I did get one side (left) to work: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/QNkwp/2/ Also, for some reason the image you're using at imgur isn't working on jsfiddle.